# How do I cut and replace xml data with simple XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with writing a simple XSLT transform. Here is the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <lst name="params">
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="Race">Elf</str>
    <int name="TraderKey">128</int>
    <str name="TraderName">TraderLato</str>
    <int name="CharacterName">Maleysh</int>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="Race">Human</str>
    <int name="TraderKey">62</int>
    <str name="TraderName">TraderSam</str>
    <int name="Comments">Farl</int>
  </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

I can't modify the format of the XML coming in, and there will be lots and lots of  nodes. I need to be able to write an XSLT 1.0 transform that will copy all the original XML but replace TraderName for certain TraderKey values. On any  node that contains a TraderKey of 128, change the TraderName to "Trader Lato Carum". Any  that contains a TraderKey of 62, change the TraderName to "Trader Samson Vero". I've never written an XSLT before, and have limited experience with XML, so this is my attempt to write an XSLT transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="response/result/doc/int[@name='TraderKey'][. = '128']>
   <xsl:value-of select="../TraderName"/>
   <xsl:text>Trader Lato Carum</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="response/result/doc/int[@name='TraderKey'][. = '62']>
   <xsl:value-of select="../TraderName"/>
   <xsl:text>Trader Samson Vero</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It doesn't work at all and I've been hammering my head against a wall for the past hour. I don't think this should be a difficult problem, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
zoombini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right lines with the identity/copy pattern you had going on, you just need a bit of conditional output.

Demo at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/ob67cg) (see output *source*)

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*' />
        <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test='@name = "TraderName" and preceding-sibling::*[@name = "TraderKey"] = 62'>
                Trader Samson Vero
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test='@name = "TraderName" and preceding-sibling::*[@name = "TraderKey"] = 128'>
                Trader Lato Carum
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select='text()' />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Utkanos, I should have been more specific. I actually want to return the entire original XML sheet, but with the TraderName values replaced. Almost like a 'search and replace'.

Comment: Wait never mind, I was using XML playground and realized it was only showing me the output, I checked the source and it looks fine. This is really great! I have a question though, what would happen if the order of elements was not guaranteed, for example, let's say that TraderKey sometimes appears before Tradername and sometimes after it. What would I use then?

Comment: An `or` condition using both `preceding-sibling::` and `following-sibling::`. Re: XMLP, yeah, I need to fix that to make it more obvious :) When outputting XML, you always need to look in the output source. I'm going to make it so that, if you output XML, it automatically shows it as a traversable tree.

Comment: `<xsl:when test='@name = "TraderName" and (preceding-sibling::*[@name = "TraderKey"] = 62 or following-sibling::*[@name = "TraderKey"] = 62)'>Trader Samson Vero</xsl:when>` --> Does that look right? EDIT: I posted this just as I saw your comment. Thanks a lot, you've been a big help. :)

Comment: Utkanos, Sorry, some unstable *moderator*♦
 has deleted part of the model thread. I don't think that I personally would need a tool such as the "XMLPlayground". There are several good XSLT IDEs. I have been using the XSelerator for the last 10+ years. Another good tool is oXygen (George Bina). Yet another tool is Kernow by Andrew Welch. Though there isn't any strong need for a tool like the XMLPlayground, you could use your experience to develop other tools, that people may be needing strongly.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - you've been warned plenty of times about posting comments to attract attention to your answers on other peoples posts. This is considered noise and you are no exception to the rule.

Comment: Oh, it is @Kev♦ ... -- I was just wondering. Well, Kev♦, we are accustomed with your attempts to prevent normal communication between SO users, when they are discussing topics related to the current question and to the current answers. Do you realize that you are doing disservice to the SO community? The next thing I would expect is to be warned not to breathe...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - we're not preventing communication that allows you to communicate about and clarify aspects or missing information in the OP's question, and the same about aspects of your answers. What we are preventing is you and everyone else from clogging up the comments with "please look at my answer" mentions. If everyone did this then any useful information to be found in comments would be lost in that noise. It's not hard to understand.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - there are a set of rules that apply to the whole community and that includes you. There is no special set of rules just for Dimitre because he doesn't think these rules apply to him. Again, if you have a problem with this then please use meta.stackoverflow.com to discuss.

Comment: @Kev♦ You cannot alter the fact that you interfered with and destroyed communication b/n two SO users on topics related to their answers. Either restore the deleted comments and apologize, or continue to pretend you haven't committed an error.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - wow, I wake up to a war. Anyway, sorry you didn't feel XMLP was "necessary". Your comments seem to suggest you don't value any online sandbox environments (e.g. JS Fiddle, which is vastly useful even though people have text editors and browsers). These have obvious uses, particularly where the demonstration of code solutions or problems is concerned. Anyway, just thought I'd ask.

Comment: @Utkanos: I cannot make any claim about JS tools, but can assure you that all XSLT professionals that I know have good XSLT IDEs and when they go to Starbucks or another hotspot equipped entertainment place, their purpose is to enjoy their families and not to use a not so good, online tool to continue writing XSLT, of which they have had enough. Writing good transformations requires focused concentration -- something that by definition isn't typically related to crowded places. Therefore, using such tools there results in suboptimal, noise-induced results. And at home we have professional IDEs

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - this discussion is perhaps not best for here (granted I started it, but I did say if you have any feedback please feel free to e-mail me - you don't have to, of course). Your points are valid, but you ignore the other primary point of online sandboxes - to demonstrate solutions or problems to people not gathered around your computer. I would have thought that benefit of them was rather inarguable.

Comment: @Utkanos: The same answer applies: Even when people are somewhere for outdoor activites and even if they are bored and want to return to XSLT programming, one can fully use their tablet and most XSLT IDEs run well on tablets. As we well know, the times have changed - it isn't "people gathered around their computer" anymore - it is people having their tablet-pc anywhere. And even on mobile phones --at last year's Balisage Michael Kay showed using SaxonCE on iPhone. This is great work, but there are significant issues with the usability of XMLP -- such as its tiny code windows and prone to DOS

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I am grateful for your thoughts. Incidentally, all the code panels have full-screen options. I still don't think what you describes negates my point about its use for demonstrating problems or solutions to people over the internet (a la Stack Overflow), but thanks for the feedback nonetheless. As I say, it's very much beta, and I hope to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution can be simple, in pure push style (without explicit `xsl:apply-templates`), without using any XSLT conditional instructions (such as `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`) -- and thus shorter, more readable and understandable**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[int[@name='TraderKey'] = 128]
          /str[@name='TraderName']
            /text()">
  <xsl:text>Trader Lato Carum</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[int[@name='TraderKey'] = 62]
          /str[@name='TraderName']
            /text()">
  <xsl:text>Trader Samson Vero</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <lst name="params"></lst></lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="Race">Elf</str>
            <int name="TraderKey">128</int>
            <str name="TraderName">TraderLato</str>
            <int name="CharacterName">Maleysh</int>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <str name="Race">Human</str>
            <int name="TraderKey">62</int>
            <str name="TraderName">TraderSam</str>
            <int name="Comments">Farl</int>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <lst name="params"/>
   </lst>
   <result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
      <doc>
         <str name="Race">Elf</str>
         <int name="TraderKey">128</int>
         <str name="TraderName">Trader Lato Carum</str>
         <int name="CharacterName">Maleysh</int>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="Race">Human</str>
         <int name="TraderKey">62</int>
         <str name="TraderName">Trader Samson Vero</str>
         <int name="Comments">Farl</int>
      </doc>
   </result>
</response>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this sheet, I didn't realize you could do all the matching within a template match.